# Combining AC and DC components in same Spectra/Molex Microfit connector

Tags: ac, dc, connector

I am making a control unit. It will interfaced with AC devices like fan, pump, light along with one DC device, namely, a Solenoid lock.

All the devices will be placed outside of the control unit.
I am planning to use 8x2 microfit connector as the interface between the control unit's PCB and the deivces.

Just wanted to know, if its a good idea to have all the above devices interfacing with the PCB via one microfit connector.

Or, should I use separate connectors for AC devices and the DC device.

Power supply and the PCB designing is all set, just wanted some guidance for the above.

Comment: Those devices don't sound like they are very pick about power quality or noise so it should probably be okay unless you are doing something out of the ordinary. You might want to separate them to meet voltage isolation requirements though if some of them use much higher voltages than the others. On the other hand, wouldn't be a pain to work with the components if they all share the same connector since they would be permanently tied together?

Comment: No, they do not consume much power or create noise. Voltage ratings are different for all of them. But the difference is not too high. Also, can you please elaborate on the pain part please? Like, they will be sharing the same connector on the PCB end... But outside the box, each one will have its own JST connector crimped on the component's end and the cable in between.

Comment: Oh, that's different. I thought they would all share the same harness and connector which would mean you would have an octopus-like assembly whenever you wanted to do anything.

Comment: Exactly. So, any thoughts on it now? Like would it matter if all the AC and DC components were connected to the PCB like the octopus-head end (if you will :P)